# Unity 3D scripts move multiple objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I'm doing a project in Unity 3D (c#), a 3D worlds editor. My problem is that I want to move multiple objects by selecting them. I managed to move one with my mouse cursor, but for multiple I failed :D 
This is my code to move one :

```
public class ClickAndDrag : MonoBehaviour {
    private RaycastHit raycastHit;
    private GameObject Gobj;
    private float distance;
    private Vector3 ObjPosition;
    private bool Bobj;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            var ray = GetComponent<Camera> ().ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            var hit = Physics.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, out raycastHit);

            if (hit && !Bobj) {
                Gobj = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;
                distance = raycastHit.distance;
                Debug.Log (Gobj.name);
            }

            Bobj = true;
            ObjPosition = ray.origin + distance * ray.direction;
            Gobj.transform.position = new Vector3 (ObjPosition.x, ObjPosition.y, ObjPosition.z);
        } else {
            Bobj = false;
            Gobj = null;
        }       
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is only coded to move an individual object. What problems are you facing moving multiple objects? You do not specify this in your question.

Comment: I dont know how to do this, because when i move one object i do this with my mouse, but i can't do that for multiple objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private GameObject Gobj;` is a variable for a *single* GameObject. Reformat it to `private List<GameObject> objects;` and instead of `Gobj.transform.position = new Vector3 (ObjPosition.x, ObjPosition.y, ObjPosition.z)` do this:

```
foreach (GameObject item in objects)
{
    item.transform.position = new Vector3 (ObjPosition.x, ObjPosition.y, ObjPosition.z)
}
```

EDIT: In case you aren't sure about how to manipulate a List, `List<T>` has a set of built in functions to make it really easy. You can now just call `objects.Add(newObject);` to add an object, and `objects.Remove(oldObject);` to remove an object.

Comment: Partial answer: you did not explain how to get this list of objects. It will not magically get filled.

Comment: To use `List<T>` you will have to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your script as well dont forget.

Comment: He wasn't asking about how to fill a list or how to select what to move... he was only asking about movement and he seems satisfied with the answer.

Comment: True but: don't lose sight that stackoverflow answers or not meant to be of use only for the OP but for the whole community.

Comment: He mentioned that he wants to move multiple objects by selecting them. So I assume the OP is building something RTS like where you should be able to select all the game objects in runtime.